# Qt, QVariant, JSON and enums

Tags: c++, json, qt, enums

I am trying to figure out how I am supposed to use enumerations in Qt so that I pack them in a QVariant and convert them to a QJsonValue and later JSON.

Following the docs I ended up declaring my enums:

```
enum BeautifulColors { Red, Green, Blue };
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(BeautifulColors);
```

That way I can use `setValue(..)` on `QVariant` to set my custom defined enums as value.

The problem however is `QJsonValue::fromVariant()`, the docs says:

> Converts variant to a QJsonValue and returns it. (...)
>   For all other QVariant types a conversion to a QString will be
>   attempted. If the returned string is empty, a Null QJsonValue will be
>   stored, otherwise a String value using the returned QString.

The conversion to `QString` fails and and my `QJsonValue` object ends up being Null.

Following the documentation further is confusing: There is a `Q_EUM` macro for enumeration definition within QObject. However since QObject is non-copy able I don't think QVariant is supposed to hold it. There are certainly some hacky was to get it working, but that is not what I am looking for. What is the recommended way in Qt to define enums so that they can be used as datatypes and converted into JSON and read from JSON?

**Update**

Tried the following:

```
rectangle.h
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

#include <QObject>

class Rectangle : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    enum Color
    {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue,
    };

    Q_ENUM(Color)

    Rectangle(double x, double y, Color color, QObject *parent = 0);

private:

    double _x;
    double _y;
    Color _color;
};

#endif

rectangle.cpp
#include "rectangle.h"

Rectangle::Rectangle(double x, double y, Rectangle::Color color, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , _x(x)
    , _y(y)
    , _color(color)
{

}

main.cpp
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

#include "rectangle.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int id = qMetaTypeId<Rectangle::Color>();
    Rectangle::Color blueColor = Rectangle::Blue;
    QVariant myVariant;
    myVariant.setValue(blueColor);
    qDebug() << id;
    qDebug() << myVariant.toString();
}
```

Now it has a typ id and a string representation! But not the class holding it:

```
int idRectangle = qMetaTypeId<Rectangle>();
```

Does not compile and I cannot register it with `Q_DECLARE_MEATYPE`, because it does not have a constructor. What if I need QVariants toString() to work with any class?

**Second Update**

Using the Q_GADGET macro I now get a (different) type id for the enum and the class holding it. However I still only get a string representation for the enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Q_ENUM` or `Q_ENUMS` are needed to generate the necessary `QMetaEnum` structure to toString/fromString functionality.

They need to be placed in a `QObject` derived class with the `Q_OBJECT` marker or in any class with the `Q_GADGET` marker in order for `moc` to process them and generate the necessary code.

The class they are defined in is not the one being stored in the variant though when you store an enum value.
You can consider this class more like a "namespace" for your enum.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3):

I figured the rest out, to be able to use `QVariant::toString()` a conversion must be registered for the type held by the QVariant.

This was added by KDAB in Qt 5.2 (http://log.cedricbonhomme.org/55/66102.html) but is nowhere mentioned in the doc `QVariant::toString()`! :(

Anyways it also works for plain enums, the following example will output "Apple"

```
enum Fruit {
    Apple,
    Pear,
    Orange
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Fruit)

QString Fruit2QString(Fruit fruit)
{
    switch(fruit)
    {
        case Apple:
            return "Apple";
        case Pear:
            return "Pear";
        case Orange:
            return "Orange";
    }

    return "asdf";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::function<QString(Fruit)> f = &Fruit2QString;
    bool success = QMetaType::registerConverter<Fruit, QString>(f);
    Q_ASSERT(success);
    QVariant v;
    v.setValue(Fruit::Apple);
    qDebug() << v.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you check if there is a bug report against documentation at Qt about this being missing?

Comment: I would suggest reporting it against component "Documentation" instead.